# Laravel 4 - Creating a XML Payment Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im making a very small application, i have decided not to use controllers and instead put everything in the routes.php file.

I have come to the stage where i need to interact with my NAB Transact payment gateway, they require an XML file sent to their server and then its sent back with all the codes and authorisations etc etc

There are some functions i need to write that will generate the XML file and im wondering if i could get some help on where would be the bes place to store these functions.

Should i write them straight into the routes.php file, i figured that was a no no but i cant find any generic place to write functions.

I would also need to incorp the failed return status into error codes to display to the user.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: For small applications such as yours, and for minor functions that are used virtually everywhere, I generally just create a file ``app/functions.php`` to place them in, then ``require app_path().'/functions.php';`` in ``app/start/global.php``.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice do not put all that on routes file, just the fact that you need to do XML calls means that your application deserve to have controllers, "code is like karma don't do things right, and they will come back to you"

Dont be afraid of creating files...

If I were you I would store my XML strings into templates and use a controller to populate them and move them around, but is you are doing payments and stuff please write a module, class or whatever you want but dont overload the controller.